# How to Visualize zPositions in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, zposition

My team and I are working on a SpriteKit based iOS game of medium complexity.  There are lots of layers and nodes to the design of the game and the zPositioning of the nodes has gotten sloppy.  One task I have agreed to take on is the revamping of our zPosition strategy: moving to constants instead of magic numbers, having a holistic zPosition scheme for the app, etc.  but first I want to analyze where we are at now.  So here is my question:

I vaguely recall watching a WWDC video (or some other tutorial, maybe) in which the person showed using some aspect of Instruments (or some other tool) to show a 3D rendering of an app, seen from an isomorphic angle, based on the zPosition of the SKNodes (or UIKit elements?) in the app.

Does anyone here know what tool this is?  And if not, what is the best way to visualize the current state of zPositions in a SpriteKit based app?  Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about View Debugging by any chance: http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: That might be what I was remembering but I sure hope not!  I was hoping for that exact same tool that could render a 3D representation based on SKNode zPositions.